# struct.pack is much slower in python 2.6 when working with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.6, binary-data

## The basic question

Hello everyone.  I believe that I found an issue with python 2.6, struct.pack, and numpy arrays.  The issue is that the following code is incredibly slow when I run it using python 2.6 (but it is sufficiently fast when I run it using python 2.7 or 2.5).

```
import numpy as np
import struct

x = np.mat(np.random.randint(0,3000,(1000,1000)))

z = struct.pack('<'+'H'*x.size,*np.asarray(x).reshape(-1).astype(int))
```

I need to be able to run something similar to this numerous times for an application that I am working on and right now my only option is to really run it using python 2.6.  I am asking if there is a faster way that I can do this using python 2.6 or if I should just spend the time trying to get a system administrator to install python 2.7 or 3.0 for me.

As far as why I need to be able to run on python 2.6 and how I figured out that this line of code was the issue see below.

## The long story

I am working on a project where I am using python to modify some files that are input into another program so that I can run a Monte Carlo simulation on that program.  Everything was going great, I wrote all the code using python 3, made sure it also all worked in python 2.7 and ran a couple test cases on my underpowered computer.  Things went pretty well.  It took about 30 seconds to run a single test case.  Then I went to port my analysis to a server that we have that is much faster/more powerful then my laptop.

I got everything working on the server but have run into a huge problem.  It now takes 30 minutes to run through a single test case.  After a little investigation I found out that the server only has python version 2.6 installed and I believe that this is the problem.  Further, I believe that the following line in particular is the issue

```
z = struct.pack('<'+'H'*x.size,*np.asarray(x).reshape(-1).astype(int))
```

where x is a numpy matrix, numpy has been imported as np, and struct has also been imported.  The reason I believe that this line is the issue follows.  First, when running this line in python 2.6 I get the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: struct integer overflow masking is deprecated
```

despite the fact that I am absolutely certain that the contents of the array I am trying to pack falls within the bounds of an unsigned short integer.  Running this same exact code using python 2.7 and 3.5 I do not get the deprecation warning either.

Further, I attempted a short test using time it.  I ran the following code using    python 2.7 and 3.0 on my local machine and got the following results:

```
python3 -m timeit "import numpy as np;import struct;x=np.mat(np.random.randint(0,3200,(1000,1000)));z = struct.pack('<'+'H'*x.size,*np.asarray(x).reshape(-1).astype(int))"
10 loops, best of 3: 467 msec per loop

python2.7 -m timeit "import numpy as np;import struct;x=np.mat(np.random.randint(0,3200,(1000,1000)));z = struct.pack('<'+'H'*x.size,*np.asarray(x).reshape(-1).astype(int))"
10 loops, best of 3: 468 msec per loop
```

which was pretty good.  I then tried to run that using python 2.6

```
python2.6 -m timeit "import numpy as np;import struct;x=np.mat(np.random.randint(0,3200,(1000,1000)));z = struct.pack('<'+'H'*x.size,*np.asarray(x).reshape(-1).astype(int))"
10 loops, best of 3: 34.4 sec per loop
```

which is an absurd 7350% increase in time...

The question I'm asking is--Is there some way that I can get around this bottleneck using python 2.6 or should I just try to get the system managers for the server to upgrade to python 3.5 or 2.7?"

Comment: You don't need to use `struct.pack` in this case.  It's going to do lots of intermediate conversions and iterate over the array sub-optimially.  Instead, use `arr.astype('<u2').tostring()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not avoid the `struct` module altogether and let `numpy` handle the binary conversion for you?

For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0, 3200, (1000, 1000))
z = x.astype('<u2').tostring()
```

`'<u2'` specifies little-endian (`<`) unsigned int (`u`) 16-bit (`2`). It's identical to `<H`.

Just to prove that they're identical:

```
z1 = x.astype('<u2').tostring()
z2 = struct.pack('<'+'H'*x.size,*np.asarray(x).reshape(-1).astype(int))
assert z1 == z2
```

And for timings (note: this is on python 2.7), the numpy version is ~100x faster:

```
In [7]: %timeit x.astype('<u2').tostring()
100 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit struct.pack('<'+'H'*x.size,*np.asarray(x).reshape(-1).astype(int))
1 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, this definitely works for the question I was asking.  I have another area where I use struct.pack though with a numpy array that has two different formats in it.  The code I am using is `struct.pack(">"+"hB"*30+"x"*27,*x.astype(int))` where every other entry in x is a short integer and the rest are 4 byte integers.  Is there an easy way to avoid this?  If you would prefer I could create a separate question.

Comment: @Andrew - Sure, anything that has a regular pattern can be expressed in terms of `dtype`s.  Casting things properly requires a trick, in those cases, though. I'll have an example in a second.

Comment: To cast a pre-existing array to the format you described you have to jump through a couple of hoops.  If you just use `astype` going from a regular array to a structured array, each field will have the same value.  Here's an example of how to do something along those lines: https://gist.github.com/joferkington/4ce9dc5960bc205eadd0

Comment: Thanks again.  That is exactly what I'm lookiung for and helps me avoid going through the loops of asking for a software install.  I think you should do a self question/answer with this info because it's really useful but difficult to figure out from just the numpy documentation (at least for someone relatively new to python/numpy).  That's up to you though.